# Python 3: How to check if a string can be a valid variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string and want to check if it can be used as a valid variable without getting a syntax error. For example

```
def variableName(string):
    #if string is valid variable name:
        #return True
    #else:
        #return False

input >>> variableName("validVariable")
output >>> True
input >>> variableName("992variable")
output >>> False
```

I would not like to use the .isidentifier(). I want to make a function of my own.

Answer (score 7):

The following answer is true only for "old-style" Python-2.7 identifiers;

```
"validVariable".isidentifier()
#True
"992variable".isidentifier()
#False
```

Since you changed your question after I posted the answer, consider writing a regular expression:

```
re.match(r"[_a-z]\w*$", yourstring,flags=re.I)
```

Comment: OP says:"I would not like to use the .isidentifier(). I want to make a function of my own." So your solution isn't answeing the question, i think. forgive me if im wrong.

Comment: Yes. @BOi is correct. your answer does not answer my question. I do not want to use .isidentifier() i want to create my own function

Comment: @RadheKrishna You changed your question after I posted my answer. Consider using regular expressions, then. (I modified the answer.)

Comment: @DyZ thqanks a lot

Comment: You can simplify the second part of your regular expression to `\\w` which matches letters, digits, and `_`.

Comment: `str.isidentifier()` and the regex expression aren't equivalent by any means.

Comment: Why aren't they?

Comment: @DyZ `>>> Ä = 1 >>> print(Ä) 1` (python3 extends identifiers to a bunch of non-ascii characters)

Comment: I think you got things backward in your edit; [`'Ä'.isidentifier()` returns True](https://ideone.com/4upGaQ) on Python 3. The regex is the one that fails on Python 3. Also, you may want to use [`keyword.iskeyword()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html) to exclude keywords.

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3 a valid identifier can have characters outside of ASCII range, as you don't want to use [`str.isidentifier`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isidentifier), you can write your own version of it in Python.

Its specification can be found here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/#specification-of-language-changes

### Implementation:

```
import keyword
import re
import unicodedata


def is_other_id_start(char):
    """
    Item belongs to Other_ID_Start in
    http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/PropList.txt
    """
    return bool(re.match(r'[\u1885-\u1886\u2118\u212E\u309B-\u309C]', char))


def is_other_id_continue(char):
    """
    Item belongs to Other_ID_Continue in
    http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/PropList.txt
    """
    return bool(re.match(r'[\u00B7\u0387\u1369-\u1371\u19DA]', char))


def is_xid_start(char):

    # ID_Start is defined as all characters having one of
    # the general categories uppercase letters(Lu), lowercase
    # letters(Ll), titlecase letters(Lt), modifier letters(Lm),
    # other letters(Lo), letter numbers(Nl), the underscore, and
    # characters carrying the Other_ID_Start property. XID_Start
    # then closes this set under normalization, by removing all
    # characters whose NFKC normalization is not of the form
    # ID_Start ID_Continue * anymore.

    category = unicodedata.category(char)
    return (
        category in {'Lu', 'Ll', 'Lt', 'Lm', 'Lo', 'Nl'} or
        is_other_id_start(char)
    )


def is_xid_continue(char):
    # ID_Continue is defined as all characters in ID_Start, plus
    # nonspacing marks (Mn), spacing combining marks (Mc), decimal
    # number (Nd), connector punctuations (Pc), and characters
    # carryig the Other_ID_Continue property. Again, XID_Continue
    # closes this set under NFKC-normalization; it also adds U+00B7
    # to support Catalan.

    category = unicodedata.category(char)
    return (
        is_xid_start(char) or
        category in {'Mn', 'Mc', 'Nd', 'Pc'} or
        is_other_id_continue(char)
    )


def is_valid_identifier(name):
    # All identifiers are converted into the normal form NFKC
    # while parsing; comparison of identifiers is based on NFKC.
    name = unicodedata.normalize(
        'NFKC', name
    )

    # check if it's a keyword
    if keyword.iskeyword(name):
        return False

    # The identifier syntax is <XID_Start> <XID_Continue>*.
    if not (is_xid_start(name[0]) or name[0] == '_'):
        return False

    return all(is_xid_continue(char) for char in name[1:])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # From goo.gl/pvpYg6
    assert is_valid_identifier("a") is True
    assert is_valid_identifier("Z") is True
    assert is_valid_identifier("_") is True
    assert is_valid_identifier("b0") is True
    assert is_valid_identifier("bc") is True
    assert is_valid_identifier("b_") is True
    assert is_valid_identifier("µ") is True
    assert is_valid_identifier("") is True

    assert is_valid_identifier(" ") is False
    assert is_valid_identifier("[") is False
    assert is_valid_identifier("©") is False
    assert is_valid_identifier("0") is False
```

---

You can check CPython and Pypy's implmentation [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a49ac9902903a798fab4970ccf563c531199c3f8/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L12020) and [here](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/3f6eaa010fce78cc7973bdc1dfdb95970f08fed2/pypy/objspace/std/unicodeobject.py?at=release-pypy3.5-v5.10.1&fileviewer=file-view-default#unicodeobject.py-527) respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression.

For example:

```
isValidIdentifier = re.match("[A-Za-z_](0-9A-Za-z_)*",identifier)
```

Note that his only checks for alphanumeric characters.  The actual standard supports other characters. See here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/

You may also need to exclude reserved words such as def, True, False, ...  see here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keywords-identifier

Comment: Your regular expression is malformed. I think you meant `[0-9A-Za-z_]` instead of `(0-9A-Za-z_)`.

Comment: Strangely enough it works in IDLE (MacOS).  Anyhow DyZ had already provided that answer (with a proper regexp).  I didn't notice it before posting.